# vba for loop to change text box value

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop, textbox

i am building an user form in which text box should pick the value from worksheet(12 sheets by month).

for example -

> textbox 500 till 526 should pick the value in jan-dec sheet cell e5 to e31.
>
> textbox 527 till 553 should pick the value in jan-dec sheet cell e38 to e64.
>
> textbox 554 till 580 should pick the value in jan-dec sheet cell e71 to e97.

can someone help me with creating a loop for generating above information??

THanks

```
Private Sub monthlist_Change()

Dim myarray As Variant
Dim X As Long

myarray = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")

For X = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)


    If Me.monthlist.Text = myarray(X) And Me.Teamlist.Text = "SDM" Then
    
        Me.TextBox500.Value = Worksheets("Functions - " & myarray(X)).Range("e5").Value
    
    ElseIf Me.monthlist.Text = myarray(X) And Me.Teamlist.Text = "Client accounts" Then
    
        Me.TextBox527.Value = Worksheets("Functions - " & myarray(X)).Range("e38").Value
    
    ElseIf Me.monthlist.Text = myarray(X) And Me.Teamlist.Text = "Class action" Then
    
        Me.TextBox554.Value = Worksheets("Functions - " & myarray(X)).Range("e71").Value
    
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited** after OP's clarifications

you would use

```
Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value = ...
```

where you would iterate over i = iMin to iMax after having set iMin and iMax accordingly

but let me also propose the following refactoring of your code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub monthlist_Change()

Dim myMnTBarray As Variant, myMxTBarray As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim mnTB As Integer, mxTB As Integer
Dim rngAddress As String

myMnTBarray = Array(500, 527, 554) '<== here you place the lower bounds of textbox names "numeric" part, corresponding to the 3 "teamlist" possible values
myMxTBarray = Array(526, 553, 580) '<== here you place the upper bounds of textbox names "numeric" part, corresponding to the 3 "teamlist" possible values


With Me
    i = .teamlist.ListIndex
    mnTB = myMnTBarray(i)
    mxTB = myMxTBarray(i)

    Select Case .teamlist.Text
        Case "SDM"
            rngAddress = "e5"
        Case "Client accounts"
            rngAddress = "e38"
        Case "Class action"
            rngAddress = "e71"
    End Select
End With

If rngAddress <> "" Then
    With Worksheets("Functions - " & Me.monthlist.Text).Range(rngAddress)
        For i = mnTB To mxTB
            Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value = .Offset(i - mnTB).Value
        Next i
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

where the only assumption is that `monthlist` listbox is populated with the array of all months names in order.

the following is only a possible code to populate a userform `monthlist` and `teamlist` listboxes

```
Sub main()

With UserForm1
    .monthlist.List = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
    .teamlist.List = Array("SDM", "Client accounts", "Class action")
    .Show
End With
Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

Comment: I must admit your code went way over my head..sorry i am new to coding. However, i tried to copy the above mentioned code and i am getting an error.

Comment: sorry let me give more info. My User for has 2 list boxes. Teamlist(It has 3 teams..sdm, client accounts, class action). Monthlist( it has 12 months). And i have a frame full of labels and textboxes(27 each). When i select the team(ex-sdm) and month(ex - january). Text box(500 to 526) should pick the data in "Functions - January" sheet range e5 to e31. when i select team client accounts textbox(527 to 533) should pick e38 to e64 from "jan" sheet. and if the team is class actions - textbox 554 to 580 should pick e71 to e97. i have 12 worksheets and the data changes every month.

Comment: I nearly got that. so I just made minor changes: substituted `monthlist` with `teamlist` in `i = .teamlist.ListIndex` and took `+1` off from `Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value = .Offset(i - mnTB+1).Value`. see edited code

Comment: I am unable to understand what you did there.. But it works amazingly perfect. I will do a research and learn what you did. Thank you so much!!! :D

Comment: If I fulfilled your question please mark my answer as the solution. you may also want to give some reps (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). An invaluable way to  know what's goin' on is stepping through the code while it runs: place the cursor on any valid statement in the main VBE module and then keep pressing F8 to step through every statement. hover your mouse over variables names to query their value. also use Immediate window to query variable values and expressions too. Finally open Locals window to check variable states/values.